# DataTables - Loop through columns/header and set width

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to loop through columns on datatable. Check the class of the header and set the width of the column.

As per DataTables docs. This is how you loop through the header but how can I set the column width?

```
<table id="data-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <?php if ($client) : ?>
            <th class="client">Client</th>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <th>Product</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
            <?php if ($client) : ?>
            <td><?php echo $client; ?></td>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <td><?php echo $product; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  var myTable = $('#data-table').DataTable();
  myTable.columns().header().each(function(value, index){
    if ( $(value).hasClass('client') ) {
       // Set column width here
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate to say it, but I dont think the answer above would ever do the trick. First of all you should target `columns()`, not `columns`; second setting a `width` on `<th>` elements does not change the browsers internal table calculation, but defining a `min-width` does. Also use chaining to be sure that `columns()` are looped *after* the DataTable is instantiated :

```
const table = $('#data-table').DataTable({
}).columns().header().each(function(th) {
  if ( $(th).hasClass('client') ) {
    $(th).css('min-width', '200px') 
  }
})
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/wvtmq5d7/**

Comment: Yeah, you're right its `columns()` not `columns`. Thank you so much man!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily do it using CSS only like:

```
.client { width: 100px; }
```

But in case you need to do some manipulation in JS to set the width, then you can do it like:

```
var myTable = $('#data-table').DataTable();
myTable.columns.header().each(function(column, index) {
  if ($(column).hasClass('client')) {
    // Set column width here
    $(column).width(100)
    
    //Or
    // $(column).css("width", 100);
  }
})
```

Please note, if no explicit unit is specified (like `"em"` or `"%"`) then `"px"` is assumed. So in the example, it is `100px` actually. You can update it as per your requirement.

Comment: How can I set a `"px"`. This one `$(column).width("100px")`?

Comment: Yes, we need to specify it as `.width("100px")`.. but that is not needed as by default it is `px`.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/205255) to help future users too. Thanks!